# Customizing dropdown menu for jquery category autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to customize the dropdown menu for [category autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories) because I have few issues with normal widget's dropdown, but I am not able to get my head around on how to do that. I am able to find resources to do for normal autocomplete widget, but not for categorized one. Below is my code.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.ui-autocomplete-category {
font-weight: bold;
padding: .2em .4em;
margin: .8em 0 .2em;
line-height: 1.5;
z-index: 2000;
}
</style>
 <script>
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
_create: function() {
this._super();
this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
},
_renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
var that = this,
currentCategory = "";
$.each( items, function( index, item ) {
var li;
if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
currentCategory = item.category;
}
li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
if ( item.category ) {
li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
}
});
}
});
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
var data = [
{ label: "TV", category: "Electornics" },
{ label: "WM", category: "Electornics" },
{ label: "M3", category: "Electornics" },
{ label: "Table", category: "Funiture" }
];
$( "#search" ).catcomplete({
delay: 0,
source: data
});
});
</script>
</head>
```

1. Other parts of web page have z-index greater than this, so the dropdown menu is hidden by few elements.
2. Dropdown style of default looks very basic and width of the dropdown exceeds the search input width if the item text is lengthy, so want to customize like below.

Can someone please shed some light on customization of categorized widget?

[image]

Comment: and whats you problem ? have you tried something ?

Comment: what do yo mean by customization ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your question is you want to change look-n-feel of category auto-complete dropdown. If that is so, here is fiddle I created for you to show how we can override the CSS to get desired look.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanpatil/a1buhpo8/9/)

You can play arround with CSS to fix the width of textbox and autocomplete dropdown like this:

```
#search{
    width: 170px;
}
.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 2000;
    width: 170px !important;
}
```

I have modified some JS code to attach icons to options in dropdown.

If some other page elements are overlapping on your dropdown then you can try increasing z-index on class **.ui-autocomplete**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, while hovering on each menu item, the highlighting of menu item in drop down has a problem, it gives only one line differentiation. Can that particular whole item be highlighted on hover? +1

Comment: Yeah. Add one more CSS rule:                                      .ui-menu-item.ui-state-focus{background-color: #4998F0;}

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you let me know how you have come to know to tweak particular styles of autocomplete, is it mentioned in api?

Comment: Welcome. No, it is not mentioned in API. Its the common way of overriding existing CSS of plugins to achieve desired look-n-feel. Its no big deal for UI developers. If you are interested, spend some time on studying CSS. And start using Chrome Developer Tool, Firefox's firebug. These tools are great to learn CSS, JS. Try manipulating CSS in these tools.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to use Icon inside your menu.
I think you could achieve same result using less code.
You should try Bootstrap to do that.
It is easy to include icons.
Try these options:
    http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/admin-side-menu
    http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/collapsible-tree-menu
    http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/sidebar-menu-group-tree